# AWS Application load balancer sending messages to Unhealthy Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've created an application load balancer and in listener setting i am forwarding my message to Target group. Target group has only instance tagged to it and it is unhealthy. Even though the instance is unhealthy messages are being forwarded from load balancer.

What do I need to do inorder to stop sending messages from load balancer to target group?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the instance from the target group. If all instances are unhealthy, LB will ignore the health checks and will still try to forward requests to them, due too lack of any alternatives.